# setText on EditText and TextView not working

Tags: android, textview

We have a bigger Android 2.1 project, and for some reason, only at two places calling `setText()` on an `EditText` or a `TextView` object just doesn't work. It does not crashes, does not throw an exception, only the `TextView`/`EditText` is not updating.

Here's the code for setting the text:

```
EditText etzip_a = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.editTextZip_a);
etzip.setText(m_addressA.zip);
etzip.addTextChangedListener(new onInputChanged(120));
```

- this code runs on the GUI thread
- it parses the `R.id.editTextZip_a` object successfully from the layout
- a totally similar code for other tens of `EditText` are working fine

Does anybody encountered a problem like this?

Comment: what is the value of m_addressA.zip. add Log to print the value of m_addressA.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using this code:

You have create a object `etzip_a`  of the EditText. Now after that you are using different object `etzip`.

```
EditText etzip_a = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.editTextZip_a);
etzip_a.setText(m_addressA.zip);
etzip_a.addTextChangedListener(new onInputChanged(120));
```

Comment: What is the difference with OP and in your answer? that you should mentioned with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText etzip = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.editTextZip_a);
```

replace this line of code